# Group data weekly according to passed date range in mysql cake php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, cakephp

I have a table jobs with following data

```
+----+------------+--------+---------------------+
| id | project_id | status | modified            |
+----+------------+--------+---------------------+
|  1 |          1 |      0 | 2014-08-23 19:48:48 |
|  2 |          1 |      0 | 2014-08-29 18:18:39 |
|  3 |          1 |      0 | 2014-08-23 19:58:55 |
| 44 |          1 |      0 | 2014-08-23 19:45:50 |
| 45 |          1 |      2 | 2014-08-03 14:38:35 |
| 46 |          1 |      3 | 2014-08-05 14:38:35 |
| 47 |          1 |      2 | 2014-08-07 14:38:35 |
| 48 |          1 |      3 | 2014-08-10 14:38:35 |
| 49 |          2 |      4 | 2014-08-14 14:38:35 |
| 50 |          1 |      0 | 2014-08-23 19:43:01 |
| 51 |          1 |      2 | 2014-08-15 14:38:35 |
| 52 |          1 |      3 | 2014-08-18 14:38:35 |
| 53 |          1 |      0 | 2014-08-23 19:49:05 |
| 54 |          1 |      4 | 2014-08-22 14:38:35 |
| 55 |          1 |      2 | 2014-09-03 14:38:59 |
| 56 |          1 |      0 | 2014-08-23 19:59:23 |
| 57 |          1 |      3 | 2014-08-27 14:38:35 |
| 58 |          1 |      4 | 2014-09-03 14:39:04 |
| 59 |          1 |      0 | 2014-08-27 17:28:45 |
| 60 |          1 |      1 | 2014-08-27 17:29:00 |
| 61 |          1 |      1 | 2014-08-27 17:29:17 |
| 62 |          1 |      0 | 2014-08-29 16:36:07 |
| 63 |          1 |      0 | 2014-08-29 16:37:24 |
| 64 |          1 |      0 | 2014-08-29 18:19:01 |
| 65 |          1 |      0 | 2014-08-29 19:17:20 |
| 66 |          1 |      1 | 2014-08-29 19:17:36 |
| 67 |          1 |      1 | 2014-08-29 19:17:54 |
| 68 |          1 |      0 | 2014-08-29 19:26:16 |
| 69 |          1 |      1 | 2014-08-29 19:26:34 |
| 70 |          1 |      1 | 2014-08-29 19:26:54 |
| 71 |          1 |      0 | 2014-08-30 19:33:59 |
| 72 |          1 |      1 | 2014-08-30 19:34:23 |
| 73 |          1 |      1 | 2014-08-30 19:35:42 |
| 74 |          1 |      1 | 2014-08-30 19:36:39 |
| 75 |          1 |      0 | 2014-08-30 19:40:52 |
| 76 |          1 |      0 | 2014-08-30 20:42:02 |
| 77 |          1 |      0 | 2014-08-30 21:27:38 |
| 78 |          1 |      1 | 2014-08-30 21:28:28 |
| 79 |          1 |      1 | 2014-08-30 21:28:59 |
| 80 |          1 |      0 | 2014-08-30 21:47:02 |
| 81 |          1 |      1 | 2014-08-30 21:47:40 |
| 82 |          1 |      1 | 2014-08-30 21:48:20 |
| 83 |          2 |      3 | 2014-08-23 18:23:12 |
| 84 |          2 |      4 | 2014-08-23 18:23:12 |
| 85 |          1 |      4 | 2014-08-23 18:23:12 |
+----+------------+--------+---------------------+
```

from which i want to get the data on Weekly basis according to the "from" and "to" dates i pass from front end. so lets suppose want data from '2014-07-15' to '2014-09-15' that should be clubbed weekly and gives sum of all jobs whose status is either (2,3,4) on a particular week for each project.

my result should be something like this

```
+--------------+---------------+---------------------+
| project_name | reviewed_jobs | modified            |
+--------------+---------------+---------------------+
| Project 1    |             0 | 2014-07-15 14:38:35 |
| Project 1    |             0 | 2014-07-22 14:38:35 |
| Project 1    |             1 | 2014-07-29 14:38:35 |
| Project 1    |             3 | 2014-08-05 14:38:35 |
| Project 1    |             2 | 2014-08-12 14:38:35 |
| Project 1    |             2 | 2014-08-19 18:23:12 |
| Project 1    |             1 | 2014-08-26 19:48:48 |
| Project 1    |             2 | 2014-09-02 18:18:39 |
| Project 1    |             0 | 2014-09-09 14:38:59 |
| Project 2    |             0 | 2014-07-15 14:38:35 |
| Project 2    |             0 | 2014-07-22 14:38:35 |
| Project 2    |             0 | 2014-07-29 14:38:35 |
| Project 2    |             0 | 2014-08-05 14:38:35 |
| Project 2    |             1 | 2014-08-12 14:38:35 |
| Project 2    |             2 | 2014-08-19 18:23:12 |
| Project 2    |             0 | 2014-08-26 19:48:48 |
| Project 2    |             0 | 2014-09-02 18:18:39 |
| Project 2    |             0 | 2014-09-09 14:38:59 |
+--------------+---------------+---------------------+
```

what i have tried so far using raw query and cake php way :

raw query :

```
SELECT projects.name as project_name, 
SUM(if((jobs.status=2 || jobs.status=3 || jobs.status=4), 1, 0)) as reviewed_jobs, 
jobs.modified FROM jobs LEFT JOIN projects ON jobs.project_id=projects.id 
WHERE jobs.modified >= '2014:08:03 00:00:00' AND jobs.modified <= '2014:09:03 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY projects.name, WEEK(jobs.modified) 
ORDER BY DATE(jobs.modified) ASC;
```

but it gives the following result

```
+--------------+---------------+---------------------+
| project_name | reviewed_jobs | modified            |
+--------------+---------------+---------------------+
| Project 1    |             3 | 2014-08-03 14:38:35 |
| Project 1    |             2 | 2014-08-10 14:38:35 |
| Project 2    |             1 | 2014-08-14 14:38:35 |
| Project 2    |             2 | 2014-08-23 18:23:12 |
| Project 1    |             3 | 2014-08-23 19:48:48 |
| Project 1    |             1 | 2014-08-29 18:18:39 |
| Project 1    |             2 | 2014-09-03 14:38:59 |
+--------------+---------------+---------------------+
```

which obviously is undesired and different from what i want and it has some potential problems as

1. if it doesn't get data of specific date (i.e 2014-08-17 in this case) it skips that week or count from the next date which is available.
2. result is not according to the dates passed in query indeed it's according to the data in table(dates available in table).

CakePHP way :

```
$options['joins']=array(array('table' => 'projects',
    'alias' => 'Project',
    'type' => 'LEFT',
    'conditions' => array(
        'Project.id = Job.project_id',
    )
));

$options['fields'] = array(
    'Project.name',
    'SUM(if((Job.status=2 || Job.status=3 || Job.status=4), 1, 0)) as reviewed',
    'DATE(Job.modified) as modified'
);

$options['order'] = array('modified'=>'ASC');

$options['conditions']=array(
    array("Job.modified >=" => $from_date->format("Y-m-d") . ' 00:00:00'),
    array("Job.modified <=" => $to_date->format("Y-m-d") . ' 23:59:59')
);

$options['group'] = array('Project.name', 'WEEK(Job.modified)');
```

Any help would be appreciable

Thanks

Comment: tl;dr - Is the problem that the result of your query does not include rows for dates that are not in your table?

Comment: yes and one more thing it should give result according to dates passed  from_date to to_date.

Comment: @GordonLinoff : it's already included in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mysql you would need another table containing all the weeks dates so you can join to that too and therefore return the weeks where there are no entries in the jobs table.

Quick and dirty way to construct weeks data:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(yr.yy,'-',wk1.d,wk2.d,'-01'), '%Y-%u-%w') yyyywkd FROM
(SELECT 0 d UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5) wk1,
(SELECT 0 d UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) wk2,
(SELECT '2013' yy UNION SELECT '2014') yr
WHERE CONCAT(wk1.d,wk2.d) > 0 AND CONCAT(wk1.d,wk2.d) < 54
```

Try this in a sub query left joined to the jobs table.

Comment: your query returns data in format yyyy-mm-dd but in table it's a timestamp of yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss so according to query it's not getting matched and resulting in empty set

Comment: one more thing even if it matches how your query gonna club data say for example form 2014-08-04 to 2014-08-11? when ur result asks jobs.modified IN <YourQuery>

Comment: Sorry but without your data set to play with I can`t do a full bit of code. For time you can add 00:00:00 to the CONCAT and %T to the date format. Put your current WHERE clause (on date) into the join and add a WHERE clause on the date my bit of code returns to restrict the returned date range.